# Is it possible to rewrite the below code in Linq/Lambda approach

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So far I have done

```
foreach (DataRow myRow in targetTable.Rows)
 {
  htmlBuilder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");

  foreach (DataColumn targetColumn in targetTable.Columns)
  {
   htmlBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
   htmlBuilder.Append(myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
   htmlBuilder.Append("</td>");
  }

  htmlBuilder.Append("</tr>");
 }
```

Any better way of doing so...like Linq/Lambda approach

Thanks

Comment: Do you even know what LINQ or C# lambdas are?

Comment: Any particular reason why?  What gains do you see by doing this in a LINQ or Lambda fashion (if you even can)?  Or are you simply trying it to see what happens (which is fine)?

Comment: Why would you like to use LINQ for this? LINQ is not magical and meant to be used for any programming task including a loop imho.

Comment: The reason is i am laerning this and want to program by using these new features

Comment: Don't program by using new features for the sake of it. Program using the best features for your section of code. In this case I think the general concensus is that LINQ is not the way to go. If you want to learn about LINQ read some tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is generally used to select and operate on a sub-set of a collection, what you're doing doesn't really fit its purpose.

You could define your foreach loops as lambdas if you really wanted to, but you won't get any special benefit. ie:

```
Action<DataColumn> buildAction = (DataColumn targetColumn) =>
{
    htmlBuilder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
    htmlBuilder.Append(myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
    htmlBuilder.Append("</td>");
};
targetTable.Columns.ForEach(buildAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest using the follow because your code is more efficient.  But since you are looking for an example to learn from… you could use the following LINQ statement to achieve the same results.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

const string ROWBEGIN = "<tr align='left' valign='top'>";
const string ROWEND = "</tr>";
const string CELLBEGIN = "<td align='left' valign='top'>";
const string CELLEND = "</td>";

targetTable.AsEnumerable()
           .Select(row => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                                        ROWBEGIN,
                                        string.Join(string.Empty,
                                                    row.Table.Columns
                                                             .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                                             .Select(column => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                                                                                             CELLBEGIN,
                                                                                             (row.IsNull(column) ? string.Empty : row[column].ToString()),
                                                                                             CELLEND))
                                                             .ToArray()
                                                    ),
                                        ROWEND)
           )
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(y => sb.Append(y));
```

Comment: That kind of indentation is not helpful in the limited space of an SO answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thinking of this as a string, consider using LINQ to XML to generate the nodes:

```
var rows = from row in targetTable.Rows.AsEnumerable()
           select new XElement("tr", 
                new XAttribute("align", "left"), 
                new XAttribute("valign","top"),
                from column in targetTable.Columns.AsEnumerable()
                select new XElement("td", 
                    new XAttribute("align", "left"), 
                    new XAttribute("valign", "top"),
                    myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString()
                )
           );
```

Translating this into Lambda syntax:

```
var rows = targetTable.Rows.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new XElement("tr", 
                new XAttribute("align", "left"), 
                new XAttribute("valign","top"),
                targetTable.Columns.AsEnumerable().Select(column => new XElement("td", 
                    new XAttribute("align", "left"), 
                    new XAttribute("valign", "top"),
                    myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString()
                ))
           ));
```

If you need the result as a string. Just call ToString() on rows.

One of the main advantages of thinking of this as XML over using a string builder is that you will properly escape invalid strings like <>&" and ensure valid XHtml as a result.